# function that can use iText to concatenate / merge pdfs together - causing some issues

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm using the following code to merge PDFs together using iText:

```
public static void concatenatePdfs(List<File> listOfPdfFiles, File outputFile) throws DocumentException, IOException {
        Document document = new Document();
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
        document.open();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        for (File inFile : listOfPdfFiles) {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inFile.getAbsolutePath());
            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                document.newPage();
                PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
                cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
            }
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        document.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }
```

This usually works great! But once and a while, it's rotating some of the pages by 90 degrees? Anyone ever have this happen?

I am looking into the PDFs themselves to see what is special about the ones that are being flipped.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are errors once in a while because you are using the wrong method to concatenate documents. Please read [chapter 6 of my book](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) and you'll notice that using `PdfWriter` to concatenate (or merge) PDF documents is wrong:

- You completely ignore the page size of the pages in the original document (you assume they are all of size A4),
- You ignore page boundaries such as the crop box (if present),
- **You ignore the rotation value stored in the page dictionary,**
- You throw away all interactivity that is present in the original document, and so on.

Concatenating PDFs is done using `PdfCopy`, see for instance the [FillFlattenMerge2](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/reporting/FillFlattenMerge2) example:

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
document.open();
PdfReader reader;
String line = br.readLine();
// loop over readers
    // add the PDF to PdfCopy
    reader = new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray());
    copy.addDocument(reader);
    reader.close();
// end loop
document.close();
```

There are other examples in [the book](http://itextpdf.com/book/examples.php).

Comment: I recognize your name from the itext namespaces. Are you a founder of the itext library?

Comment: Yes, I'm that Lowagie ;-)

Comment: Question - copy.addDocument doesn't exist in my version of itext. am I too old? 5.0.6

Comment: yep 5.5.0 worked. i thought i was grabbing latest from maven repository but i accidentally mis clicked when i went to copy paste. crap.

Comment: Now a better question - why didn't you have to close your file output stream? Does document.close() do that for you?

Comment: Yes, `document.close()` also closes the `PdfWriter` instance and the `OutputStream` used by the writer. You can prevent this by using `writer.setCloseStream(false);`. For instance: if you have a `ZipOutputStream` to which you're adding multiple PDFs, you don't want iText to close that stream.

Comment: The code where I'm calling .close() seems to work, but you're saying then I don't need it. OK. Thanks for the great info. I have confirmed the rotating pages are gone now with your help.

Comment: @NicholasDiPiazza, if you have found your own solution, even using another answer, make your own answer, don't try to [modify another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4592838).

Comment: more of an attempt to add on to his answer the correct version of the function i attempted to write above. I can make as a new answer

Answer (score 13):

In case anyone is looking for it, using Bruno Lowagie's correct answer above, here is the version of the function that does not seem to have the page flipping issue i described above:

```
public static void concatenatePdfs(List<File> listOfPdfFiles, File outputFile) throws DocumentException, IOException {
        Document document = new Document();
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, outputStream);
        document.open();
        for (File inFile : listOfPdfFiles) {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inFile.getAbsolutePath());
            copy.addDocument(reader);
            reader.close();
        }
        document.close();
}
```